# Pulling together History data from multiple attribute tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design

I have a terribly designed set of database tables that contain data for vessels. The vessel attributes are split up into their own tables (vessel name, length, horsepower, etc). When a vessel is updated we insert a new record into the appropriate attribute table with an effective date so we can keep history.

I need to pull this data into a flat object that shows what the vessel looks like through history. So if name and length were both edited on the same day it would only have one record for that day.
Please refer to the following to better explain the existing data and desired results.

**Existing DB Tables**

```
Vessel  
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|  
|      vessel_id      |        CG#       |   Modified_Date  |  
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|  
|          1          |        123       |     01/01/2000   |  
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|  

Vessel_Name  
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|  
|      vessel_id      |      Name        |   Modified_Date  |  
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|  
|          1          |   Sea Queen      |     01/01/2000   |  
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|  
|          1          |   Sea King       |     01/01/2001   |  
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|  
|          1          |   Sea Goddess    |     03/01/2005   |  
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|  

Vessel_Horsepower  
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|  
|      vessel_id      |      HP          |   Modified_Date  |  
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|  
|          1          |       50         |     02/01/2000   |  
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|  
|          1          |       75         |     01/01/2003   |  
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|  
|          1          |      115         |     03/01/2005   |  
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

**Desired Results**

```
Vessel_History  
|------------|------------|------------|------------|----------------|  
| vessel_id  |     CG#    |    name    |     HP     | effective_Date |  
|------------|------------|------------|------------|----------------|  
|     1      |     123    | Sea Queen  |    NULL    |   1/1/2000     |  
|------------|------------|------------|------------|----------------|  
|     1      |     123    | Sea Queen  |     50     |   2/1/2000     |  
|------------|------------|------------|------------|----------------|  
|     1      |     123    | Sea King   |     50     |   1/1/2001     |  
|------------|------------|------------|------------|----------------|  
|     1      |     123    | Sea King   |     75     |   1/1/2003     |  
|------------|------------|------------|------------|----------------|  
|     1      |     123    |Sea Goddess |     115    |   3/1/2005     |  
|------------|------------|------------|------------|----------------|
```

I have inherited this database and I cannot make changes to its design at this time.

Comment: Help us help you - please share the table definitions, some sample data, and the result you'd like to get for that sample.

Comment: @Mureinik I added a diagram that got left off my original posting.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Your Test Data
with vessel(id, cg, modified_date) as
 (select 1, 123, to_date('01012000', 'DDMMYYYY') from dual),
vessel_name(id, name, modified_date) as
 (select 1, 'Sea Queen', to_date('01012000', 'DDMMYYYY')
    from dual
  union all
  select 1, 'Sea King', to_date('01012001', 'DDMMYYYY')
    from dual
  union all
  select 1, 'Sea Goodess', to_date('03012005', 'DDMMYYYY')
    from dual),
vessel_horsepower(id, hp, modified_date) as
 (select 1, 50, to_date('02012000', 'DDMMYYYY')
    from dual
  union all
  select 1, 75, to_date('01012003', 'DDMMYYYY')
    from dual
  union all
  select 1, 110, to_date('03012005', 'DDMMYYYY')
    from dual)

-- Select:
select m.id,
       -- determine value of table "vessel" for current id, modified_date 
       (select cg
          from vessel n
         where n.id = m.id
           and n.modified_date =
               (select max(nn.modified_date)
                  from vessel nn
                 where nn.id = n.id
                   and nn.modified_date <= m.modified_date)),
       -- determine value of table "vessel_name" for current id, modified_date 
       (select name
          from vessel_name n
         where n.id = m.id
           and n.modified_date =
               (select max(nn.modified_date)
                  from vessel_name nn
                 where nn.id = n.id
                   and nn.modified_date <= m.modified_date)),
       -- determine value of table "vessel_horsepower" for current id, modified_date 
       (select hp
          from vessel_horsepower n
         where n.id = m.id
           and n.modified_date =
               (select max(nn.modified_date)
                  from vessel_horsepower nn
                 where nn.id = n.id
                   and nn.modified_date <= m.modified_date)),
       m.modified_date
  from -- collect all modified_dates of an id:
        (select v.id, v.modified_date
           from vessel v
         union
         select v.id, v.modified_date
           from vessel_name v
         union
         select v.id, v.modified_date
           from vessel_horsepower v) m;
```